# MiniCssExtractPlugin no carga bien fuentes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, fuentes

Honestamente no parece tener relación, pero me ocurre que desde que uso el MiniCssExtractPlugin, el template.min.css que carga los estilos generales le está asignando una ruta más a las fuentes. Las fuentes funcionaban bien con el 'style-loader' pero no era óptimo apra el código. Ahora los estilos funcionan, las fuentes siguen siendo generadas en public/default/font, pero cuando tiro el npm start veo que el path que está buscando es el que adjunto en las fotos (como si lo buscara dentro de public/default/css/public/default/font.

Un resúmen del webpack:

```
    output: {
      publicPath: 'public/default/',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/public/default'),
      chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].chunk.js',
      filename: 'js/template.min.js'
    },
        {

          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']

        },
        {

          test: /\.less$/,

          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {loader: 'css-loader'},
            {
              loader: 'less-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: argv.mode === 'development'
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|webp)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'img/build/[hash][ext][query]'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
          generator: {
            filename: 'font/[hash][ext][query]'
          }
        }
    plugins: [
      new RetryChunkLoadPlugin({
        maxRetries: 3
      }),
      new Dotenv({systemvars: true, defaults: true}),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'css/template.min.css',
        chunkFilename: 'css/[id].css'
      })
    ]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]